# Can I load from 2 different hdb roots in one KDB service?

Tags: kdb

Say I have two different subfolders in my hdb directory, folder A and folder B. Both have the data inside partitioned by date and the sym files enumerated against each individual table.  Directory A has 1 sub table, `quote and directory B has another table `trade.  I am able to load both of these directories into my q session individually using:

```
system "l /dir/A"
system "l /dir/B"
```

When I then attempt to click on the tables that were in directory 'A' I face the following error in QStudio:

```
kx.c$KException: ./2020.04.21/quote. OS reports: No such file or directory
```

Now if I go an execute the following again:

```
system "l /dir/A"
```

The error  disappears but I face the same style of error when I now try and click on the trade table.  Does anyone know if it's possible to load from two separate directories into one service?

Answer (score 2):

The problem here is that this second hdb load `system "l /dir/B"` overwrites the first. When you load a hdb, kdb maps it into memory and uses the sym file to display enumerated sym cols in their original human readable form. It can only use 1 sym file to do this as enumerated columns are actually an index to where they are in the sym file and it wouldn't make sense to reference more than 1.

I think you should look at having them as one date partitioned hdb but if this is not an option you could setup 2 hdb processes with ports you can connect to:

```
// start hdbA with quotes
q /dir/A -p 12345

// start hdbB with trades
q /dir/B -p 23456

// connect to hdbB from hdbA
hdbB:hopen `::23456;
// example query 
hdbB"select from trades where date = .z.d"

// connect to hdbA from hdbB
hdbA:hopen `::12345;
// example query
hdbA"select from quotes where date = .z.d"
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer Matt - I thought it was the sym file being overwritten as well so I made sure to have a distinct sym file per table using the guide under "using multiple sym files" here: https://code.kx.com/q/wp/symfiles/#appendix-for-versions-of-kdb-earlier-than-36
So as of right now, to expand on my question the sym file in folder A is called symA and sym file for folder B is symB.  Thanks for the suggestion on running a second process, this is currently what I'm trying to avoid but will explore as last resort!

Comment: I believe that multiple sym file article is for having more than one sym file in the one hdb. There will still be issues with mapping the hdb as you likely have the same dates in the 2 hdbs which leads to confusion of what is stored where. If this is a question of space and the 2 hdbs are on different drives par.txt could be your answer. https://code.kx.com/q/kb/partition/ You could have 1/2 dates in hdbA and the other 1/2 of dates in hdbB.

Answer (score 2):

If you have two different sym files not of the same name then you're in luck - you can simply create a synthetic database using symbolic links where the links point to both tables and then you can load the synthetic database. Of course maintaining the synthetic database is another issue but it's not too challenging. It would look like this:

```
synthdb/
    2020.01.01/
        trade -> /db1/2020.01.01/trade
        quote -> /db2/2020.01.01/quote
    2020.01.02/
        trade -> /db1/2020.01.02/trade
        quote -> /db2/2020.01.02/quote
    splay1 -> /db1/splay1
    splay2 -> /db2/splay2
    flat1 -> /db1/flat1
    flat2 -> /db2/flat2
    sym -> /db1/sym
    sym2 -> /db2/sym2
```

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to do without symlinks. Andrey Kozyrev wrote the code that moves between loaded HDB and sym files. You can find it under his https://github.com/quintanar401/DCoQ

```
.db.db:.db.dbm:(0#`)!(); .db.cdb:`;
.db.sdb:{if[not null .db.cdb;.Q[`sym`date]:(sym;date);.db.db[.db.cdb]:.Q;![`.;();0b;key .Q.dbt]]};
.db.ldb:{if[x in key .db.db;.db.cdb:x;.Q:.db.db x;`sym`date set' .Q`sym`date;system"cd ",.Q.dbp;set'[key .Q.dbt;value .Q.dbt]]};
.q.dbl:{.db.sdb[];system "l ",x;.db.cdb:last` vs`$":",x;.Q.dbp:x;.db.dbm[(` sv/: .db.cdb,/:t),t where{$[98=type x:get x;-11=type value flip x;0b]}each t:tables[]]:.db.cdb;.Q.dbt:t!get each t;};
.q.db:{if[null d:.db.dbm x;'x];if[not .db.cdb=d;.db.sdb[];.db.ldb d];last ` vs x};
```

then
dbl"/kdb/history/fx" and then use db`trade as a reference to a table